# How do I change the order of MacFamilyTree events?

Tags: macfamilytree

I'm using MacFamilyTree 9.

Whenever I add a new person, the order of events is as following:

- Burial
- Christening
- Death
- Occupation
- Birth

Ideally, it'd be something like

- Birth
- Christening
- Occupation
- Death
- Burial

It was like that until recently. I'm not sure what I could have done that changed it.

Comment: I find the order changes into date order as I add in information with dates. I'm not sure why the default is like that to start with - I don't find it logical either! Perhaps its related to the availability of the information with most common sources listed first for ease of reference.